# Calculate arithmetic function - Möbius inversion

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, mobius-inversion

An arithmetic function $f$ has the property $$\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if n is divisible by a square of a prime} \\ n & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Calculate $f(6300)$.

I have done the following :

From the Mobius inversion formula we get $$f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu (d)g(n/d)$$ where $g$ is the above defined function.

We have that $6300=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot 7$

So as $d$ do we take all $54$ divisors? Or just the prime ones $2,3,5,7$ ?

Comment: I am having trouble interpreting your specification for $$\sum f(d).$$  Do you intend that $$\sum f(d) = 0 ~: ~\text{if} ~n~ \text{is divisible by a square} ~>  1~?$$  If so, please edit your posting accordingly.  If not, please edit your posting to clarify your intent.

Comment: Yes, that's right! @user2661923

Comment: Please edit your posting.

Comment: I edited it! What values do we take for $d$ ? Only the prime ones? @user2661923

Comment: If $n$ is divisible by any square $~> 1~$ then $n$ has to be divisible by the square of a prime.  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Alternatively if you are asking what the range of $d$ should be in your summation formula at the start of your posting, I do not know.  My knowledge of Number Theory has decades of cobwebs on it.  I had to pull out a textbook to make the initial editing suggestion that I did.

Comment: I got stuck right now. We want to calculate $f(6300)$ . So do we have then $f(6300)=\sum_{d\mid 6300}\mu (d)g(6300/d)$ where $g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)$ ? Or have I understood that wrong? @user2661923

Comment: You are asking the wrong person.  My knowledge of Number Theory has decades of cobwebs on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)=g(n) $

where $g(n)=\begin{cases} 0& \text{ if n is divisible by a square of a prime} \\ n & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$

Then $f=\mu\star g$. Since it's easy to see that $g$ is multiplicative, this implies that $f$ is also multiplicative.

Let $n=\Pi_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{a_i}$ . Then by multiplicative property of $f$ , we have

$\begin{align}f(n) &=\Pi_{i=1}^{k} \mu\star g(p_i^{a_i})\\&=\Pi_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=0}^{a_i}\mu({p_i^{a_{i}-j}) }{g(p_i^{j})}
\end{align}$

---

Given $n=6300=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot 7$

$\begin{align} f(6300)=&\sum_{j=0}^{2}\mu({2^{2-j}) }{g(2^{j})}\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{2}\mu({3^{2-j}) }{g(3^{j})}\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{2}\mu({5^{2-j}) }{g(5^{j})}\cdot\sum_{j=0}^{1}\mu({7^{1-j}) }{g(7^{j})}
\end{align}$

---

$\begin{align} &\sum_{j=0}^{2}\mu({2^{2-j}) }{g(2^{j})}\\&=\mu(2)g(2)\\&=-2\end{align}$

$\begin{align} &\sum_{j=0}^{2}\mu({3^{2-j}) }{g(3^{j})}\\&=\mu(3)g(3)\\&=-3\end{align}$

$\begin{align} &\sum_{j=0}^{2}\mu({5^{2-j}) }{g(5^{j})}\\&=\mu(5)g(5)\\&=-5\end{align}$

$\begin{align} &\sum_{j=0}^{1}\mu({7^{1-j}) }{g(7^{j})}\\&=\mu(7)g(1)+\mu(1)g(7)\\&=-1+7\\&=6\end{align}$

---

$f(6300) =-2\cdot(-3) \cdot(-5) \cdot 6=-180$

Comment: typo alert: at the start of your answer, in your specification for $g(n).$

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)